# NFC Programming in Android and ACR122U reader

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, hce, acr122

I need to write some data into an NFC tag, the tag I need is not a physical NFC tag but I need to make a tag programatically and write my data into it (card emlation or peer-to-peer mode). This tag which I make in the phone has to be readable by the ACR122u reader. How can I program this in Android?

Answer (score 1):

ACS have an [Android development toolkit](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=drivers&id=ACR122U). You'll need an on-the-go USB cable. I've got a [couple of apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Thomas%20Rorvik%20Skjolberg) in Google Play which do similar stuff you can try.

Comment: Thanks!
Is there any tutorial or sample code on how to use the Android Development Toolkit?

Comment: It is, included in the driver download. But it kind of hairy.